# How do I use the FB Graph API to retrieve a user's mobile phone?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I use the FB Graph API to retrieve a user's mobile phone? Is this even possible? It's not listed as part of the extended permissions, but I was wondering if there was a way I could retrieve that piece of information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get access to a user's mobile phone number via the graph api

Comment: Is there a recommended way to obtain it?

Comment: It seems to be possible now? http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87398

Comment: It was available for about two days and then they disabled it after complaints. It is yet to be re-enabled