# Mobile Number Info in API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, phone-number

Egypt's NTRA recently approved changes for available 3 Mobile operators "MobiNil", "Vodafone" and "Etisalat" to increase all existing numbers by an extra digit to become 11 digits instead of 10.

Due to this, several problems would occur for Mobile number authentication and problems with Phonebooks like this one in Facebook.

I'm trying to build an application where it checks for user's Mobile number, checks whether it's in Egypt or not then verifies number in new format or old format. If it was an old format, users get a prompt with a button and notification to change number from XXX to YYY.

I searched the Graph API but unlucky found no details about Mobile number.

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the mobile phone number from a user. I spent a good bit of time previously trying to figure it out. It's a shame!

[How do I use the FB Graph API to retrieve a user's mobile phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698558/how-do-i-use-the-fb-graph-api-to-retrieve-a-users-mobile-phone)