# get mobile_phone data

Tags: facebook, permissions, social-networking

I found several posts about get mobile_phone data, as follows:

**Developer Posts:**

- [Improvements to Permissions for Address and Mobile Number](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447) (The features displayed on this "oficial" page are not working)
- [Platform Updates: New User Object fields, Edge.remove Event and More](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446)

**User posts:**

- [Facebook API - How to get user's address, phone #?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3402270/facebook-api-how-to-get-users-address-phone)
- [cannot ask permissions for user_mobile_phone & user_address](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=87398)
- [How do I use the FB Graph API to retrieve a user's mobile phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698558/how-do-i-use-the-fb-graph-api-to-retrieve-a-users-mobile-phone)
- [Mobile Number Info in API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7757621/mobile-number-info-in-api)

  and others ...

But they are old posts ... My question is if currently there is any way to capture this data (mobile phone of the logged user or friends of the logged user) using facebook app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted on comments on Developers Blog post [Platform Updates: New User Object fields, Edge.remove Event and More](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/446) those fields and permissions not working anymore.

BTW, this info was never available for user's friends, as described in same blog post

**Update:**
First blog post you linking too ([Improvements to Permissions for Address and Mobile Number](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447)) lists those features as *"temporary"* disabled

> We’ll be working to launch these updates as soon as possible, and will be temporarily disabling this feature until those changes are ready. We look forward to re-enabling this improved feature in the next few weeks.

No later info was provided on Developers Blog